# Frame and bounds not being updated while setting constraints

Tags: swift

While creating constraints, it seems like the frame and bounds of a constrained UI element is not being updated immediately.

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            counterLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            counterLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: timeLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: view.frame.size.height/100),
            counterLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.size.width/1.2),

            gameButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: (view.bounds.size.height-counterLabel.frame.maxY)) // THIS DOES NOT WORK
```

It turns out that despite creating the constraints for counterLabel, its frame and bounds are still (0,0,0,0). The solution that I found to work was putting the gameButton's height anchor within viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Why is this the case? I tried looking for other threads and documentation about this, but couldn't find much.

Comment: Where do you activate the constraints? Where do you check the view's frame/bounds?

Comment: I am activating the constraints inside viewWillLayoutSubviews. I am only concerned about the contentLabel's frame/bounds because I use it to calculate my gameButton's height anchor.

Comment: Not directly related to your issue but you should not be setting constraints in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. That method can be called many times. Better to setup constraints once in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write layoutIfNeeded() before using frame or bounds
for example

```
layoutIfNeeded()
myView.layer.cornerRadius = myView.frame.width / 2
```

now frame and bounds returns true values

in your case, maybe you need to set constraints, then calculate them and store your constraints in variables.

Comment: That make sense! So because my code relies on Auto Layout, at that point the layout engine had not updated positions. Running layoutIfNeeded() manually prompts the layout engine to update.

I didn't explicitly follow what they wrote, but added layoutIfNeeded() before I created and activated the gameButton's height anchor

Comment: @HangarRash This is the right solution! The given code is not well-written it needs to be refactored  again to get the true result. The way they are calculating and writing their constraints is not the recommended way! they are using the old-fashion way but using auto layouts.I just answered why Frame doesn't return true value.

Comment: This is far from ideal because it requires that `layoutIfNeeded` be called and the button's constraint to be updated every time the frame of the label changes. This eliminates the whole point of using constraints. The proper solution is to use proper constraints and avoid the need to call `layoutIfNeeded`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to set the button's height as a constant based on values that can change over time, you should set the button's top and bottom anchors so its height will adjust accordingly.

Replace:

```
gameButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: (view.bounds.size.height-counterLabel.frame.maxY))
```

with something like:

```
gameButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: counterLabel.bottomAnchor),
gameButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
```